# How to fectch data from DIM table attributes as a columns based on fact table key

Tags: ssas, mdx

[image]

We are using don’t net application for customized reports with MDX scripting. I am new for writing the MDX queries. Can anyone help for fetching the data from the below question.

1. For each CPKey we have List of patients
2. For each Patient information available in Patient dim table.

How can I retrieve patient information as a column from Patient DIM table, when I have the CPKey from the dot net application by the MDX?

Expected result set like below

```
PatientID   PatientName MemberNum   Phone   Age Gender  Conditions
1   abc 12345   111111  25  F   NULL

![Sql >>>>>
Select  p.* from 
 ConditionprevalencePatient  cpp
Inner join patient p
On p.Patientid = cpp.Patient

MDX ???????][2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the conditions and your screen shot in the question has some relationship lines covered by tables, but an MDX query would look something like:

```
SELECT {} ON COLUMNS,
       [Patient].[Patient ID].[Patient ID].Members
       *
       [Patient].[PatientName].[PatientName].Members
       *           
       [Patient].[MemberNum].[MemberNum].Members
       ...
       ON ROWS
  FROM [YourCubeName]
 WHERE {
       [ConditionPrevalencePatients].[ConditionPrevalenceKey].[12345],
       [ConditionPrevalencePatients].[ConditionPrevalenceKey].[67890]
       }
```

MDX is very different from SQL, even if on the first view, you recognize some keywords.